# Drupal How to reload javascript file

Tags: javascript, drupal, optimization

I have a problem with a drupal site I didn't designed and which I have to modify.
The theme is a subtheme of Omega theme.

The problem is that I modify the main.js file and uploaded it back to the site, I cleared the cache, but when i tried to reload the page the loaded js is still like the old one, and has the name:

main.js.pagespeed.jm.IModC23.js

I think there could be a javascript file optimization module somewhere..
I can't find a system to make the page load the new javascript. I even go to the Performance page a uncheck "Aggregate javascript file"
Maybe the solution is easy but I couldn't find it anywhere..

Thank you

Comment: why to modify the main.js? You can create and add your js file with drupal_add_js

Comment: I don't want to add another js file. I just need to modify the main-ck.js file. I don't understand why the page still load the old one instead of loading the modified version. And the search through the files of the site didn't bring me any result where drupal_add_js where used with the main-ck.js file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like pagespeed is aggregating all your js.

To turn it off you can put:

```
ModPagespeed off
```

in your .htaccess file and then turn it on again when your done.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997217/pagespeed-caching-css-annoying-to-develop) is talking about the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that it was a question of time for the cache. The day after appeared to work properly...