# CSS file path changes on the browser

Tags: html, css, path

I have specified the following css path but when i am trying to load page it converts the file path as below 
In the html code i had given the path like :

```
     <link href="css/style.default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But after inspecting on browser it gets converted as below:

```
<link href="css/A.style.default.css.pagespeed.cf.cgR25iXVvw.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: please check now i have updated my code

Comment: It looks like pagespeed is caching CSS. Read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997217/pagespeed-caching-css-annoying-to-develop)

Answer (score -1):

It is your server changes filepath. This is because you have turned on addidtional cache for files.